# How to Forecast Non-Numeric Data

Tags: r, logistic

Is it possible to include non-numeric data in logistic regression i.e. education level and occupation? This is a dataset for [kaggle credit card approval prediction](https://www.kaggle.com/rikdifos/credit-card-approval-prediction). I can create IDs to represent the education level i.e. 1 for higher eduction, 2 for secondary, etc. but I'm not sure if it would give me reliable results. I'm just learning.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Your results may depend on how precisely you code the data (education tends to be successive, but occupation not) and too many categories can weaken your model if you have a limited number of observations, but that is part of model building

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression works just like OLS regression in this regard: nominal predictors are translated to dummy coding. Try the following code:

```
expl <- data.frame(category = gl(3, 10, labels = c("red", "blue", "pink")),
                   sold = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                            1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
str(expl)
model <- glm(sold ~ category, data = expl, family = "binomial")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(expl) +
  geom_count(aes(x = category, y = sold))

summary(model)

predict(model, newdata = data.frame(category = c("red", "blue", "pink")),
        type = "response")
```

`sold` is predicted by `category`. There are three levels of `category` so R constructs two dummy variables. You can see them in the model summary:

```
> summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = sold ~ category, family = "binomial", data = expl)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.552  -1.094   0.000   1.094   1.552  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    0.8473     0.6901   1.228   0.2195  
categoryblue  -0.8473     0.9361  -0.905   0.3654  
categorypink  -1.6946     0.9759  -1.736   0.0825 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 41.589  on 29  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 38.298  on 27  degrees of freedom
AIC: 44.298
```

So there is a dummy variable for blue and one for pink. None is needed for the base category as that is included in the Intercept.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure how to mark a comment as answer.)

Thank you Henry. The fewer the variables the better the model. I'll use variables like education where it's obvious how to assign numeric value in correlation to value i.e. the higher the education level the higher the numeric value.